# weird result when filling a matrix one array at a time in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, indexing

I am trying to fill a matrix in python in a straightforward (probably not efficient) way:

```
coord = [0]*3
coords = [[0]*3]*4

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        coord[j]= i
    coords[i] = coord
```

I would expect the output for "coords" to be [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]

but instead I am getting [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]

is my matrix algebra bad, or is there something I don't understand about python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for such result is that for each `i` `coords[i]` will store the reference to the same object. Modifying `coord` hence results in modification of every item in `coords`.

Generaly in Python you do not want to declare list size in advance. You should just declare an empty list and then append new item to it.

Refactoring your code like this will give you desired output

```
coords = []
for i in range(4):
    coords.append([i]*3)
print(coords)
```